# Convert a Google Earth KmlPolygon into KML string

Tags: google-earth-plugin

If I have a [KmlPolygon](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_polygon) object, how might I convert this to a KML string? This functionality would allow you to save whatever has been modelled and use it as a layer in Google Earth desktop for instance, or even load it back into the web plugin.

**EDIT**

This would do the opposite of [fetchKml](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/kml).

Answer (score 0):

Found it. You can use the `getKml()` function of [KmlFeature](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_feature.html#a77cfbea4c20f85136a7ed7f85aa60c3e) to return the KML string. You can also add multiple KmlPolygon objects by constructing a KmlDocument using the [dom.buildDocument()](http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/wiki/GEarthExtensionsDomReference#buildDocument%28children,_options%29) of the utility library, and then using `getKml()` on that.